# Graphing a parabola

Tags: graph-drawing

I have to draw filled parabola now I'm just drawing parabola using:

```
double dt = 0.0001;
for(double x = -50; x < 50; x+= dt){ // drawing parabola from -50 to 50
    double y = x*x;
    pic.drawPoint(x, y, cr, cg, cb); // x point, y point , R G B
}
```

What should I change here in order to make it fill the inside of parabola ?

Comment: Do you mean you would like to draw parabola with a fill or just connect the point with a line?

Comment: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s490/sh/8ce5c6be-6f27-40bb-a5fd-6b32debdfb76/b20e3e5dbce6b9c77c71cb7146f8c843  filled like this. Don't mind the axis and the arrows.

Comment: What are you using for plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved I just added another loop

```
double dt = 0.0001;
for(double x = -50; x < 50; x+= dt){ // drawing parabola from -50 to 50
   double y = x*x;
   for(double yy = y; yy < maxY; yy+=dt){ 
       pic.drawPoint(x, yy, cr, cg, cb); // x point, y point , R G B
  }  
}
```